# How to parse the JSON string from invoked adapter in Worklight

Tags: objective-c, json, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

We have a JSON file in the server. We were able to retrieve the JSON file, but apparently we could not get the items in the nested JSON.

Here is the snippet of our code:

```
- (void)onSuccess:(WLResponse *)response{
    NSLog(@"Connection Success: %@",response);
    NSString *resultText;

    if ([response responseText] != nil) {
        resultText = [response responseText];

        NSDictionary *allData = [response getResponseJson];
        NSDictionary *resultData = allData[@"result"];
        ...
      }
}
```

Below is our JSON file structure:

```
{"contacts":[
    {
        "name":"name 1",
        "address":"address 1"
    },
    {
        "name":"name 2",
        "address":"address 2"
    },
    {
        "name":"name 3",
        "address":"address 3"
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [valueForKeyPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/valueForKeyPath:) after you have an NSDictionary on the client.

For example, pseudocode:

```
NSArray* contacts = [allData valueForKeyPath:@"result.contacts"];
NSString* firstContactName = contacts[0][@"name"];
```

I assume your NSDictionary referenced by `allData` has the contacts NSArray in the `results.contacts` key path. If that's not the case, modify according to the structure of your NSDictionary.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the late reply. We tried to implement this in our code. Unfortunately, we are getting this error: *[ERROR] Worklight: -[WLClient onInvokeProcedureFailure:userInfo:]:932*

Comment: Did you resolve this issue WLClient onInvokeProcedureFailure:userInfo: because i am facing the same